# Nav submenu hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nav menu that displays it's subnav on hover. The issue is when I hover over the subnav, the subnav disappears.

If I remove the subnav's `z-index` it fixes the hover issue, but now the subnav is above the main nav.

How do I fix this so subnav is below main nav AND able to be hovered.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/rXBgNR?editors=0110) Example

Answer (score 2):

Super basic example using css hover

The key points are

- subnav is contained inside nav
- subnav is `display: none` until the nav has `:hover` (position and animation instead if you want to match your current implementation)

https://jsfiddle.net/7mb0szLk/1/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for my purpose.

I've set the following style to subnav:

```
.subnav-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 20px 0 !important;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  background: gray;
/*   z-index:-1; */
}
```

I needed to eliminate `z-index` because I would not be able to interact with any elements within it since its' negative index. Also, I needed it to be positioned absolute, so it doesn't take up any space, hence it doesn't push contents below it down.

I added `visibility:hidden` and `height:0` so I can animate those properties and achieve the slide/drop down effect.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/rXBgNR?editors=0110)